# How to replace any odd number of backslashes using JAVA

Tags: java

I am not able to replace any odd number of backslashes in Java. Below is the code i have used. It's working fine for replacing even number of Backslashes.

#### Code

```
String x = "I am having a \ great time";
x = x.replace("\\\", " ");
```

Comment: you can't have a single backslash in java. it has to be escaped and therefore you always have 2 backslashes at once

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a backslash is an escape character in Strings. So you cannot use a backslash without an appropriate character after it.

Escape sequences are characters that have a special meaning. For example, a new line is represented using `\n`. You can take a look at all valid escape sequences in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

To represent a backslash itself, you will need two backslashes `\\`.

So, in effect, you cannot use *Odd* number of backslashes on their own in Java.

In your example, you should use just two backslashes `\\`.

```
String x = "I am having a \\ great time";

x = x.replace("\\", " ");
```

So your result becomes:

```
"I am having a   great time"
```

> **Update**:

The data from your excel sheet will get stored in memory in Java as is. So, *to help you understand*, if you have a sequence of `\\\` characters in your excel data, it will get translated to `\\\\\\` in Java automatically. So you don't have to worry about it.

For example, If your excel sheet contains something like this:

[image: Excel Data]

Then your Java String will be represented as:

[image: Java String]

By simply using the `x = x.replace("\\", " ");`snippet in your Java Code, it will take care of replacing all the `\` characters to spaces automatically.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.

But i am taking data from the excel sheet where odd number of backslashes exists. So, how to replace it, any idea..?

Comment: When you read data from excel sheet and put it into a string in Java, it will already be escaped. So you don't need any special handling. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks anacron.. But I have a string with single or odd number of backslashes.. If you have any idea how to remove it, please help me for the same

Thanks a lot

Comment: I understand and that is what I'm trying to help you with. The above code snippet should work no matter how many ` \ ` characters you have in your Excel. Did you try using the above methods? Is it failing ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape backslashes in Java strings. This.

```
String x = "I am having a \ great time";
```

Doesn't even compile. You have to do this:

```
String x = "I am having a \\ great time";
```

It doesn't mean that you have two backslashes. It is one backslash that had to be escapded by another, since backslash is the so called "escape character" in Java. You can see this by doing

```
System.out.println(x);
```

Your final code should be this:

```
String x = "I am having a \\ great time";
x = x.replace("\\", " ");
```